# Fetching an Oracle cursor into a PHP array?

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to fetch an Oracle cursor into a variable `$cursor1`:

```
$cur = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":out_cursor", $cur,-1, SQLT_RSET);
oci_execute($cur);
$cursor1 = oci_fetch_assoc($cur);
```

Unfortunately this only returns the first row from the cursor.

If I loop through using a while statement I can get all of the results:

```
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($cur))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

However, I'm calling this procedure many times throughout the system and the cursor returns different datasets with each call - I need to be able to place it all into a generic array if possible.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but `oci_fetch_all()` seems to do the trick:

```
oci_fetch_all($cur, $cursor1, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
```